# SMC-Python Adding and Removing Blacklisted IP's

Tags: python

I'm trying to programmatically add a blacklisted IP to the firewall. I try this but get an error. I'm not that new to python, but I'm not all that proficient in reading the documentation, so here is that if it helps.

https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/smc-python/latest/smc-python.pdf

https://smc-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

```
from smc import session
from smc_monitoring.monitors.blacklist import BlacklistQuery
from smc.core.engines import Engine
from smc.administration.system import System

session.login(url='http://nope', api_key='supersecret')
print("logged in")

# #   Method 1  ERROR
system = System()
print(system.smc_version)
system.blacklist(src='1.1.1.1/32', dst='2.2.2.2/32', duration=3600)
session.logout()
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/matthew/PycharmProjects/GitSMC/BlacklistTest.py", line 12, in
>
> system.blacklist(src='1.1.1.1/32', dst='2.2.2.2/32', duration=3600)
>
> File
>   "/home/matthew/PycharmProjects/GitSMC/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/smc/administration/system.py",
>   line 159, in blacklist
>       json=prepare_blacklist(src, dst, duration, **kw))
>
> File
>   "/home/matthew/PycharmProjects/GitSMC/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/smc/base/mixins.py",
>   line 32, in make_request
>       result = getattr(request, method)()
>
> File
>   "/home/matthew/PycharmProjects/GitSMC/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/smc/api/common.py",
>   line 66, in create
>       return self._make_request(method='POST')
>
> File
>   "/home/matthew/PycharmProjects/GitSMC/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/smc/api/common.py",
>   line 101, in _make_request
>       raise err
>
> smc.api.exceptions.ActionCommandFailed: Invalid JSON format: At line 1
>   and column 17, end_point1 is not recognized as JSON attribute.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ways to blacklist, either through the System entry point like you have above, or individually against a single firewall/cluster.
If using the System entry point, the blacklist entry will go to all SMC managed firewalls.
Based on the message, it appears you might be using a newer version of smc-python (i.e. >6.5.x).

In that case it's best to use the engine level blacklisting:

```
from smc.elements.other import Blacklist

engine = Engine('myfw')
blacklist = Blacklist()
blacklist.add_entry(src='1.1.1.1/32', dst='2.2.2.2/32')
engine.blacklist_bulk(blacklist)
```

I just noticed that the System entry point does not have a blacklist function for SMC 6.5 (which hasn't technically been fully certified for this library yet), but I will add to the develop branch as 6.5.x will be officially supported in the next couple of weeks.

If you are using SMC version <= 6.4.x, you can use the engine.blacklist, or System.blacklist commands.

DLP